# Understanding scale up in HazelCast

Tags: java, caching, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have a problem in understanding  Distributed Executor Service.I am trying to run the example which is mentioned here in

[a link] https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/distributed-executor/scale-out

What i am assuming about scale out is that when i run master and slave on different Machines the execution should happen on both machines i.e load should be balanced on both machines.But i am not able to see anything happening on slave console.The master console is executing all the 1000 EchoTask.Is my understanding wrong about  Distributed Executor Service?Can someone help me in understanding this

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct. When you start up the nodes, are they able to connect to each other? Do you actually see a cluster being formed or work both of them independently?

Latter case can happen if your network does not work with multicast and nodes are not able to discover each other automatically.

Can you basically share some logging to see that the nodes form the cluster as expected?